# Insert on 3 joins MYSQL

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do is to insert records from multiple tables into 1 table by joining. Here is what I have and I can't seem to get it to work. I get the following error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
INSERT INTO users(`name`, `email`,`location_id`, `department_id`)
VALUES('John Doe', 'jdoe@email.com', 1, 1)

INSERT INTO extensions(`ext`)
VALUES(98765)

INSERT INTO dids(`did`)
VALUES('1-800-555-5555')

INSERT INTO users_numbers(user_id,ext_id,did_id) 
SELECT extensions.*, dids.*, users.*
FROM extensions tbl_ext, dids tbl_dids, users tbl_users, users_numbers usn
Inner Join users ON users.id=usn.user_id 
Inner Join extensions ON extensions.id=usn.ext_id 
Inner Join dids ON dids.id=usn.did_id
WHERE tbl_users.name = 'John Doe' 
AND tbl_users.email = 'jdoe@email.com' 
AND tbl_ext.ext = 98765 
AND tbl_dids.did='401-559-9999';
```

The first 3 insert statements work. The error fires on the 4 insert when I try to join. Can anyone help.

Comment: Don't mix old-style implicit joins (listing all the tables separated by comma) with ANSI JOIN syntax. It's best to use ANSI JOIN for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, the `SELECT` list has to return only the columns that you want to insert into the table. The error is because you're returning `tablename.*` rather than specific columns.

Second, the `SELECT` query is very wrong. You have the tables that you're joining listed twice: first in the `FROM` clause and then again in the `INNER JOIN` clauses. You should only list them once (unless you're doing a self-JOIN, which is not needed here).

And you shouldn't be joining with `users_numbers` -- that's the table you're trying to add to, so it doesn't have the IDs for these rows yet.

What you want is a simple cross join between the rows from each of the source tables that match the values you're combining into the relation table.

```
INSERT INTO users_numbers(user_id,ext_id,did_id) 
SELECT u.id, e.id, d.id
FROM users AS u
CROSS JOIN extensions AS e
CROSS JOIN dids AS d
WHERE u.name = 'John Doe' 
AND u.email = 'jdoe@email.com' 
AND e.ext = 98765 
AND d.did='401-559-9999';
```

Comment: thanks it doesn't error out but i get 0 rows inserted.

Comment: I made a mistake when I type out my query. It works now. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
INSERT INTO users(`name`, `email`,`location_id`, `department_id`)
VALUES('John Doe', 'jdoe@email.com', 1, 1);

SET @user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO extensions(`ext`)
VALUES(98765);

SET @ext_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO dids(`did`)
VALUES('1-800-555-5555');

SET @did_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO users_numbers(user_id,ext_id,did_id)
VALUES (@user_id,@ext_id,@did_id);
```

Instead of using user variables (`@user_id,@ext_id,@did_id`) you can also fetch the `LAST_INSERT_ID` in your application language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very specific about which columns you want from that `SELECT`. Right now you're grabbing everything from the three tables, that's too much.

Maybe you mean:

```
INSERT INTO users_numbers(user_id,ext_id,did_id)
  SELECT users.id, extensions.id, dids.id
    FROM ...
```

When composing complicated queries like this, run the `SELECT` subcomponent separately to ensure it produces the right data. I bet if you ran your version it'd show a bunch of columns.

Comment: When I ran the query  it duplicated every record in the users_numbers tables

Comment: @RaymondFeliciano You have the `users_numbers` table in the `SELECT` query. So it's selecting rows from the table and then inserting them again. Maybe you wanted to do an `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`?